# Firebase cannot create documents after deletion

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is that I create a collection through the application, then I delete this collection through the application, and I want to create it again, but it does not. When I go out and re-enter the application, I can create it.My first creation and deletion is running smoothly.The application does not show an error, but the program continues to run, but does not form a data firebase.

Create data code is here :

```
db
    .collection("Cart")
    .document((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!)!)
    .collection("Cart")
    .document().setData([
        "imageURL" : self.imageURL,
        "Foodname" : self.foodName,
        "Platecount" :self.plateCount,
        "Owneremail" :self.emailText,
    ])
```

Deletion code is here :

```
self.db
    .collection("Cart")
    .document((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!)!)
    .collection("Cart")
    .addSnapshotListener{ (snapshot, err) in
                         if err != nil {
                             print (err?.localizedDescription)
                         } else {
                             if snapshot?.isEmpty != true && snapshot != nil {
                                 for document in snapshot!.documents {
                                     self.db.collection("Cart").document((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!)!).collection("Cart").document(document.documentID).delete()
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
```

Comment: There are many ways the two snippets you shared can be run in relation to each other, and some of those ways may work while others don't. Can you edit your question to contain a single snippet of code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem? Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `.document((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!)!)` this is going to be a problem - [Constraints on document IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits). Also, it's not clear why there's a need for a subcollection called 'Cart' within the *Cart/email/document*. Can you clarify as it seems unnecessary - just add the fields within the document.